# How to get an average mean of columns Flask/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate an average of two columns 'Height(Inches)' and 'Weight(Pounds)', when i use the code below , i getting the error 500 'Internal Server Error'.

```
@app.route('/csv')
def get_average_parameters():
dataset = pd.read_csv('hw.csv')
average = dataset[['Height(Inches)', 'Weight(Pounds)']].mean()
return str(average)
```

But when use 'average' without columns sigs:

```
@app.route('/csv')
def get_average_parameters():
dataset = pd.read_csv('hw.csv')
average = dataset.mean()
return str(average)
```

I didn't get any error, and output looks like this:

```
Index 12500.500000 Height(Inches) 67.993114 Weight(Pounds) 127.079421 dtype: float64
```

How can I get the averages of two columns 'Height(Inches)' and 'Weight(Pounds)' without errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way is correct, but it's wrong that you return the value directly as a string. `dataset.mean()` returns a series, that is why your output looks like that. In order to just get the mean of certain column, lets say height column, you just have to do it like this

```py
average['Height(Inches)']
```

So you can modify your return statement like this

```py
return f"Average Height: {average['Height(Inches)']}, Average Weight: {average['Weight(Pounds)']}"
```

Or if you just want to return in a shape of array you can

```py
return f"{average.values[1:]}"
```

Why starts with 1? because index 0 is your dataframe index